# findViewById to return array of Views

Tags: android

I have the same `View` inflated (from XML) multiple times. When I call `findViewById(R.id.my_layout).setVisibility(View.GONE)` I want to apply it on all such views.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't a version of `findViewById()` that returns all matches; it just returns the first one.  You have a few options:

1. Give them different ids so that you can find them all.
2. When you inflate them, store the reference in an `ArrayList`, like this:

   ```
   ArrayList<View> mViews = new ArrayList<View>();
   ```

   Then when you inflate:

   ```
   LayoutInflater inflater = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   mViews.add(inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, root));
   ```

   Then when you want to hide them:

   ```
   for (View v : mViews) { v.setVisibility(View.GONE); }
   ```
3. Depending on what you're doing with these Views, the parent layout may have a way of accessing them.  E.g., if you're putting them in a `ListView` or some such.  If you know the parent element you can iterate through the children:

   ```
   ViewGroup parent = getParentSomehow();
   for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); ++i) {
       View v = parent.getChildAt(i);
       if (v.getId() == R.id.my_layout) {
           v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
   }
   ```

If the above options don't work for you, please elaborate on why you're doing this.

Comment: If i've to apply only to a one, how do I identify that?

Comment: I don't understand.  If you want to uniquely identify a `View`, you need to give it a unique ID, or perhaps use the `View.setTag()` method to store custom data with the `View`.

Answer (score 1):

Modify on the `View` that holds the inflated layout.

E.g:

If you have

`View v = inflater.inflate(.... );`

you change the visibility onto this view. `v.setVisibility(View.GONE);`