# Is there a way to grab a collection of Views with a particular identifier?

Tags: jquery, android, arrays, class, view

I'm working with a LinearLayout that contains a number of TextViews.  Some of those TextViews belong to one functional category, and I'd like to refer to them in a jQuery-esq manner.  I have

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1"...
```

and so on, with text2, 3, 4, ..., but these identifiers are unique.  Is there something similar to CSS classes, so from code I can then refer to a multitude of Views at once, via an array?

What would be ideal is to have something like the following:

```
View[] views = getAllViewsofClass( c );
```

Then in the layout xml I'd have something like

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" class="c"...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is similar question with answer: [findViewById to return array of Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129030/findviewbyid-to-return-array-of-views)

If you want to access views via array you have to manually iterate through result of inflation or children of layout.